# ant-testng task for passing multiple test class names(passing through cmd line args)

Tags: ant, testng

I want to invoke an ant task which should accept multiple test classes for testng and run(not suite xml), 
very similar to   but comma separated list of test classes. I could not find any clue when I checked the documentation.
Is there a possibility, Please let me know.

This is my ant task to run a single test:

```
<target name="run-class"
    description="run a specific test class. Requires class.name property set to fully-qualified name of class">
    <some properties />
    <testng classpathref="lib.path"
            outputDir="${outputDir}"
            workingDir="${workingDir}"
            verbose="2"
            useDefaultListeners="false"
            listeners="${testng.listeners}"
            className="${class.name}"
            delegateCommandSystemProperties="true"
            configFailurePolicy="continue">
        <jvm params/>
    </testng>
</target>
```

I would invoke this as :  `ant run-class -Dclass.name=com.vmware.CreateVM -DParallel=true`

I would like to provide another ant task as above which should accept multiple test classes(but not as a suite xml file)

Comment: What have you found yet?

Comment: It would really help if you posted example of what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [TestNG Ant Task](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) documentation and look at the `classpath` and 
`classpathref` attributes and `classfileset` element.